# Quaternions vs Axis + angle

Tags: quaternions

I have been trying to find the difference between the two but to no luck minus this:

> The primary diff erence between the two representations is that a
>   quaternion’s axis of rotation is scaled by the sine of the half angle
>   of rotation, and instead of storing the angle in the fourth component
>   of the vector, we store the cosine of the half angle.

I have no idea what

> sine of the half angle of rotation

or

> cosine of the half angle

means, could someone explain?

Comment: Please use blockquotes (`> ` at the beginning of the line) rather than code formatting for your quotes. Also, where do you have the quotes from?

Comment: *I'm not conversant in quaternions, but here's an attempt*

If you rotate it by $\theta$, then they want $\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Also, have you looked at [Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) on wikipedia?

Answer (score 2):

Let $E = \mathbb{R}^3$ be an euclidien oriented vector space, $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{R} \oplus E$ be the quaternion algebra. Let $R_{\theta,\vec{u}}$ be a rotation of $E$ with axis $\vec{u}$ a unit vector and angle $\theta$. Then what your quote means is : The quaternion associated to $R_{\theta,\vec{u}}$ is the element $q_{\theta,\vec{u}} := (\cos(\theta/2),\sin(\theta/2)\vec{u}) \in \mathbb{H}$.

More precisely, the map $\mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}, z \mapsto q_{\theta,\vec{u}} z q_{\theta,\vec{u}}^{-1}$ stabilize the subspace $E$ and is equal to $R_{\theta,\vec{u}}$ on that space.